# insert before each match using awawk, sed or bash

Tags: bash, awk, sed

I want to change the file with the following contents:

```
[Peer]
PublicKey = gpS4RheuHn+/RIyT+H2Eur3nPxOKxSLDXPtyt1vqFAg=
AllowedIPs = 10.0.0.2/32

[Peer]
PublicKey = 8j/QYgGxeqMNRrKe5V/yQpBf8k8gX63bDBmeuKWhDTY=
AllowedIPs = 10.0.0.3/32

[Peer]
PublicKey = 6lcI+cBb79SS1v60kG63QPvoHvegP1ESqOjeZReUBwo=
AllowedIPs = 10.0.0.4/32

[Peer]
PublicKey = UqMYp8SbLvdnRpWG9t3Ve9SMKvmASnWE0w0XIe9XGQc=
AllowedIPs = 10.0.0.5/32

[Peer]
PublicKey = S7bbWxHECZfbnzJrDGcQOvGHq4/E7rAn4LAemtrDnRs=
AllowedIPs = 10.0.0.6/32

[Peer]
PublicKey = rSu3IGLcSZTiWTPyBRC0U12N5Ho6TMIHVfXu2An7Fyo=
AllowedIPs = 10.0.0.7/32
```

to

```
# Peer: 1
[Peer]
PublicKey = gpS4RheuHn+/RIyT+H2Eur3nPxOKxSLDXPtyt1vqFAg=
AllowedIPs = 10.0.0.2/32

# Peer: 2
[Peer]
PublicKey = 8j/QYgGxeqMNRrKe5V/yQpBf8k8gX63bDBmeuKWhDTY=
AllowedIPs = 10.0.0.3/32

# Peer: 3
[Peer]
PublicKey = 6lcI+cBb79SS1v60kG63QPvoHvegP1ESqOjeZReUBwo=
AllowedIPs = 10.0.0.4/32

# Peer: 4
[Peer]
PublicKey = UqMYp8SbLvdnRpWG9t3Ve9SMKvmASnWE0w0XIe9XGQc=
AllowedIPs = 10.0.0.5/32

# Peer: 5
[Peer]
PublicKey = S7bbWxHECZfbnzJrDGcQOvGHq4/E7rAn4LAemtrDnRs=
AllowedIPs = 10.0.0.6/32

# Peer: 6
[Peer]
PublicKey = rSu3IGLcSZTiWTPyBRC0U12N5Ho6TMIHVfXu2An7Fyo=
AllowedIPs = 10.0.0.7/32
```

I tried with:

```
awk '/[Peer]/{print "# Peer: "++c} 1'
```

but doesn't work. Many double output.

I want to insert a word `# Peer: sequence number` before each match.

I try with awk, it gives me many double output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> try with awk '/[Peer]/{print "# Peer: "++c}1' but doest work. Many
> double output.

You have forgotten about escaping `[` and `]`, `/[Peer]/` means any line containing `P` or `e` or `e` or `r`, add `\` escape sequences that is do

```
/\[Peer\]/{print "# Peer: "++c}1
```

and your code should work as intended, though keep in mind that this will check if line contain `[Peer]` anywhere, if you wish to limit to `[Peer]` spanning whole line do

```
$0=="[Peer]"{print "# Peer: "++c}1
```